# Using powershell Select-Object with a property that contains a square bracket

Tags: powershell, ssas, adomd.net

I am getting a dataset back from a SSAS model via `AdomdClient` which gives me an object with properties that have names with square brackets in them. This is preventing me from being able to use `Select-Object` to only select a subset of properties (or more specifically to use calculated properties to rename them so that they match another dataset/obj)

I am aware of issues around using square brackets in file names and have tried escaping the brackets. Ideally I would like to learn of a powershell way to handle these properties, although any answers that explain a way to get the `adomdclient` to return the data back without the brackets would also be very helpful for my specific goal of renaming the properties.

This code snippet below can recreate what I am seeing without the SSAS/adomdclient dependencies. I am using powershell 5.1 for this code due to a assembly dependency:

`````
$bracketedTestObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "MyProperty[WithBrackets]" = "bracketedValue"
    "MyPropertyWithoutBrackets" = "nonbracketedValue"
}

Write-host "The whole obj"
$bracketedTestObj | ft

Write-host "Select just the non bracketed property"
$bracketedTestObj | select-Object "MyPropertyWithoutBrackets" | ft

# I cannot figure out how to escape the [] and select only the bracketed property 
Write-host "Select just the bracketed property"
$bracketedTestObj | select-Object "MyProperty[WithBrackets]" | ft

Write-host "Select just the bracketed property, 1 backtick"
$bracketedTestObj | select-Object "MyProperty`[WithBrackets`]" | ft

Write-host "Select just the bracketed property, 2 backtick"
$bracketedTestObj | select-Object "MyProperty``[WithBrackets``]" | ft

Write-host "Select just the bracketed property, 3 backtick"
$bracketedTestObj | select-Object "MyProperty```[WithBrackets```]" | ft

Write-host "Select just the bracketed property, 4 backtick"
$bracketedTestObj | select-Object "MyProperty````[WithBrackets````]" | ft
`````

results (I did not include the results with more than ` backtick, but the result is the same:

```
The whole obj

MyPropertyWithoutBrackets MyProperty[WithBrackets]
------------------------- ------------------------
nonbracketedValue         bracketedValue          


Select just the non bracketed property

MyPropertyWithoutBrackets
-------------------------
nonbracketedValue        


Select just the bracketed property

MyProperty[WithBrackets]
------------------------
                        


Select just the bracketed property, 1 backtick

MyProperty[WithBrackets]
------------------------
```

Comment: Well this is quite interesting, could be a bug? You can definitely use `$bracketedTestObj.PSObject.Properties.where({$_.Name -match '\['})` but it is of course not the intended way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my best knowledge, there's no way to force `Select-Object` to *not* attempt to expand wildcard sequences in property names.

Safest workaround is to use a calculated property that evaluates the target property on the input item:

```
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
  'MyProperty[WithBrackets]' = 123
  'OtherProperty' = 456
}

$object |Select-Object @{Name='MyProperty[WithBrackets]';Expression={$_.'MyProperty[WithBrackets]'}}
```

To keep it DRY, you might want to write a small utility function to generate such calculated property definitions:

```
function New-LiteralPropertySelector {
  param([string[]]$PropertyName)

  foreach($name in $PropertyName){
    if([WildcardPattern]::ContainsWildcardCharacters($name)){
      # Property name contains wildcard characters -> special handling required
      Write-Output @{Name=$name;Expression={$_.$name}.GetNewClosure()}
    }
    else {
      # No wildcards, return as-is
      Write-Output $name
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
  'MyProperty[WithBrackets]' = 123
  'OtherProperty' = 456
  'ImportantProperty' = 789
}

$object |Select-Object @(New-LiteralPropertySelector 'MyProperty[WithBrackets]','ImportantProperty')
```

And get the expected results:

```
MyProperty[WithBrackets] ImportantProperty
------------------------ -----------------
                     123               789
```

Answer (score 4):

If the brackets are part of the wildcarding, like `Select-Object MyProp*`, then maybe...

```
PS C:\> $bracketedTestObj|Select-Object 'MyProperty[[]WithBrackets[]]'

MyProperty[WithBrackets]
------------------------
bracketedValue
```

[Edit: this feels like it shouldn't work, like the `[]]` should break it, or the whole outer `[...]` should take any of the letters inside it in scrambled order, but quick testing neither of those problems seems to happen].

A workaround, wildcards that match a single character:

```
Select-Object "MyProperty?WithBrackets?"
```

Comment: It works! I wonder how did you find it out lol

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon just [trial-and-error a few things](http://pastie.org/p/1KofKa8QsKhGigPd3yoWMG)

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I did use the single wildcard approach to get the changes that I need done today. I am going to accept Mathias' answer just because their function handles the odd edge case of having multiple properties like `prop[[a]],props[a]x` and selecting the right one. If I could give you some more of these internet points I would though, this is a great answer and helped me "just get it done" today